# Select from mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables,

```
categories:
ID, category
"1","Cars"
"2","Trucks"
"3","Bikes"
"4","Planes"
"5","Boats"

users:
ID, username
"1","john"
"2","bob"
"3","billy"

users_categories:
ID, userid, categoryid
"1","1","1"
"2","1","2"
"3","2","2"
"4","3","3"
```

Now I need to select users who have multiple categories(that i specify), so in this example, I need a query that selects only the user "john" who has categories 1 and 2. I will pass the categories that I need in the query. i.e 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in pure SQL, though post-processing is definitely possible. What language are you using to call the mysql?

Comment: im using php (yii) in a web application to call this.

Comment: `id` in the users_categories table appears to be redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more than 2 categories is needed, this query gives required users:

```
SELECT userid
FROM user_categories
WHERE 
   categoryid IN (1,2)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

note: `having count(*) = xx` must be equal to a number of categories passed to `IN ( ... )` list.


To retrieve user names, join the above query to `users` table:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
JOIN (
  SELECT userid
   FROM user_categories
   WHERE 
      categoryid IN (1,2)
   GROUP BY userid
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) q
ON u.id = q.userid;
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58651/4

Answer (score 1):

Edit: meh, missed the detail about selecting the username, not constraining by the username.

Here is the correct answer:

```
SELECT * FROM `users_categories` AS `uc`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON `u`.`ID`=`uc`.`userid`
WHERE `uc`.`categoryid` IN (1,2)
GROUP BY `uc`.`userid`
HAVING COUNT(`uc`.`userid`) >= 2
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdca/9

Leaving the original answer for historical purposes.

---

Yes, this is possible with table joins.

The constraints are `username` and `categoryid` ...for *john*:

```
SELECT `c`.* FROM `users` AS `u`
INNER JOIN `users_categories` AS `uc` ON `uc`.`userid`=`u`.`ID` AND `uc`.`categoryid` IN (1,2)
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `c`.`ID`=`uc`.`categoryid`
WHERE `u`.`username`='john';
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdca/1

---

The query will also work if you remove the `categoryid` constraint (to get all categories for a given username) by removing `AND uc.categoryid IN (1,2)` ...for *billy* this time:

```
SELECT `c`.* FROM `users` AS `u`
INNER JOIN `users_categories` AS `uc` ON `uc`.`userid`=`u`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `c`.`ID`=`uc`.`categoryid`
WHERE `u`.`username`='billy';
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdca/3

---

Furthermore, if you already know the user's ID, this can be simplified even further ...for *bob* (id #2) now:

```
SELECT `c`.* FROM `users_categories` AS `uc`
INNER JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `c`.`ID`=`uc`.`categoryid`
WHERE `uc`.`userid`=2;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fdca/5